# Start a BackgroundService ExecuteAsync method from REST call in NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, background-service

I have implemented a NET Core BackgroundService following the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio). Its method `ExecuteAsync` runs when a program starts, and this works fine.

How can I, however, execute a background job (located in `ExecuteAsync` method of `BackgroundService` interface) not just from program start but, say, via a REST call?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question correctly. Do you want to start BackgroundService from let's say REST call? Not on application startup via `.AddHostedService<>`, right?

Comment: If it's intended to be a background service, then you wouldn't directly initiate it via a REST call. Instead you would have it process jobs out of some sort of queue. You could do that via a scheduling library (such as [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/)) that checks for new work in the queue periodically. Or you could do it via a message queue service, such as RabbitMQ or Azure Service Bus, perhaps using the [MassTransit library](https://masstransit-project.com/).

Comment: Create a table or other storage mechanism and have your BackgroundService pick up "pending jobs" from that table.  Then from your REST just insert new "pending jobs" to the table.

Comment: Do you want to start a job or only execute action once from controller?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to achieve it's not possible to directly insert a "worker" job into the BackgroundService. 
However you could schedule a job in a queue (queue or database or whatever) or use an event message system for your backgroundworker to consume.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can do this:

```
public class Controller
{
   private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProdiver;

   public Controller(IServiceProvider serviceProdiver)
   {
       _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
   }

   public async Task RunAllBackgroundServices()
   {
      var allBackgroundServices = _serviceProvider.GetServices<IHostedService>();

      foreach(var hostedService in allBackgroundServices)
      {
          await hostedService.StartAsync(CancellationToken.None);
      }
   }
}
```

With DI you will fetch all implementation of `IHostedService` and run them.